# Rename Files with increment Numbers

Tags: files, rename

I have files in `/root/test/access.log.1` to `999` and `/root/test/error.log.1` to `999`.

I would like to rename `access.log.1` to `access.log.2` and move to `/var/log/archives/`, and same way `error.log.1` to `error.log.2`.

I tried something like below

```
#!/bin/bash
NEWFILE=`ls -ltr |grep error |tail -2 | head -1 |awk '{print $9}'`
for i in `ls -ltr |grep error |tail -1`;
do
    mv "$i" /var/log/archives/"$NEWFILE"
done
```

Comment: That script is way more complicated than what you're asking, so please edit the question to clarify exactly what you need.

Comment: To clarify, this fits your description, but it's trivial: `mv /root/test/access.log.1 /var/log/archives/access.log.2; mv /root/test/error.log.1 /var/log/archives/error.log.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `bash` script:

```
for file in {access,error}.log.{999..1}; do
    echo "$file" "/path/to/dest/${file//[0-9]}$((${file//[a-z.]}+1))";
done
```

- `${file//[0-9]}`, this removes digits and keep alphabet only which will result `error.log.` or `access.log.` part.
- `${file//[a-z.]}`, this removes alphabet and dots only (I write `a-z.` because of your files name patterns), which will result numeric part; and
- `$((${file//[a-z.]}+1))` will increment one to the numeric part as produced by above.

This will rename files as below and move to `/path/to/dest/`:

```
access.log.999 --> /path/to/dest/access.log.1000
access.log.998 --> /path/to/dest/access.log.999
...
error.log.999 --> /path/to/dest/error.log.1000
error.log.998 --> /path/to/dest/error.log.999
...
```

Note that replace `echo` for dry-run with `mv` to have rename on files.

Comment: file moving as like below

access.log.52 --> /path/access.log.5253
access.log.53 --> /path/access.log.5354

Comment: see my update..

Answer (score 1):

We could run something along the lines of

```
perl -E 'for (reverse 1..999){
            rename( "access.log.$_" , "access.log.".($_+1))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# exit on error
set -e

# increase the numbers of the old archives (mv -i avoids accidental overwrite)
for ((i=999; i >= 2; i--)); do
    for name in access error; do
        if [[ -e /var/log/archives/$name.log.$i ]]; then
            mv -i "/var/log/archives/$name.log.$i" "/var/log/archives/$name.log.$((i+1))"
        fi
    done
done

# move current files to archives
for name in access error; do
    mv -i "/root/test/$name.log.1" "/var/log/archives/$name.log.2"
done
```